# Need help to understand part of a lecture on linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

I am watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpX0TSAcdJY&t=1429s&spfreload=1#t=1144.111294) video on 1:17:50

and I do not understand the statement that professor makes: 
why $yAx = cx = yb$ implies that every $x$ has the same objective, which means all $x$ are optimal. I do not really understand what David Karger is saying here...
I will appreciate explanation! Thank you
[image]